# Git is not pushing repository to github

Tags: git, github

I have added and committed my project. I created a remote repository. I used git remote add origin https.. to my repository. When I use git push origin master, it says Everything up-to-date, but nothing is showing up on github. Github just has it listed as created.

Answer (score 3):

Check if there is still changes in your status by using `git status`. If yes then add them all `git add .` If you did not commited on git bash yet, then do it `git commit -a -m` ”your message”’. Then `git push origin master`.